# Could not install Pl/pythonu (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, postgresql, plpython

I am using postgreSQL v9.3 on Windows 8.1 64x. Failed to create extension plpythonu:

```
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/plpython2": No such file or directory
```

How i can resolve it?

Comment: Do you have Python 2 installed? I think Pg 9.3 requires Python 2.7, but it might be 2.6... you can check by opening plpython2 with dependency walker (depends.exe).

Comment: Can it be because of 64 bit edition of my Widnows?

Comment: Your Python install must match the PostgreSQL you installed. So if you installed a 32-bit PostgreSQL you must install a 32-bit Python, and vice versa.